# SCIPY multi-dimensional minimization

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, scipy, linear-programming

currently I have a lot of variables as 2D np.arrays.  But I would to use then to solve linear systems like:

```
min W
st:
w >= U - S
W >= 0
```

I alredy tried to use np.optimize.minimize as:

```
>>> W0=np.zeros((2,4))
>>> U = np.array([[18, 0, 0, 10],[210,0,0,20]])
>>> S = np.array([[16, 8, 12, 8],[80, 160, 80, 80]])
>>> cons = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x - U + S})
>>> res = minimize(lambda x: x, W0, constraints=cons)
```

This last step result in error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,) (2,4)
```

The expected solution is:

```
 array([[   2, 0, 0, 2],
        [ 130, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Thanks

**EDIT**:

I could solve using:

```
 res=np.array([[minimize( fun, (0), bounds=[(0,None)], constraints = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x -U[r,m] + S[r,m]})).x[0] for m in range(4)] for r in range(2)])
```

Comment: This looks like a linear programming problem, for which there is [linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html). But I don't understand what you mean by "min W" when W is a matrix.

Comment: @zaq: W is a machine/resource matrix, for example.  The matrix notation is conveniently, but each cell is a independent system.

Comment: Scipy.minimize performs "Minimization of __scalar__ function of one or more variables." It's not going to solve a bunch of minimization problems at once.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using:

```
res=np.array([
               [
                 minimize( fun, (0), bounds=[(0,None)], 
                   constraints = ({'type':'ineq', 
                     'fun': lambda x: x -U[r,m] + S[r,m]}
                   )
                 ).x[0] 
                f or m in range(4)] 
              for r in range(2)]
            )
```

So I'm calling R.M minimization problems